# Multiple google ads on a single page using infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adsense

I know google limits ads on a page to only 3 of the same unit but I notice some sites that can load more than 3 of the same unit. This sites are usually single page sites that uses infinite scroll.

A great example is [EliteDaily](http://elitedaily.com/life/dear-anxiety-instead-toxic-turned-stronger-person/1001860/). Try scrolling down and notice the leaderboard being loaded on scroll (the one centered align).

I tried implementing the same using [InfiniteScroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) but the ads are just showing up to 3. More than that, it is not showing anymore.

How could this be possible? Is it the said technique legal? Won't google block me since I am displaying more than the max requirement of ads on a page?

Comment: You could also just move the existing ones couldnt you? Another idea would be to create an iframe and load another ad within this frame (not sure if working)

Comment: I haven't tried this but I think this is a violation to their rule? I read somewhere that you should not load it in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely limited to [three ad units per page](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ad_limit_per_page)

However, you could dynamically move those ad units around the page. That said, some sites can arrange a special publishing deal with google to get around the standard restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean by "you could dynamically move those ad units around the page"? Does that mean the EliteDaily has dome "publishing deal" with google that is why they could load more than 3 ad units on their page via infinite loader?

Comment: Just have the ad code within a div, that you can later clear, and reinsert somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mean the if I have 3 divs with 1 ad unit in each then I add another, i'll just pop the first ad unit it push it to the last? And so on? With that, it will leave the top divs empty as it is push it to the bottom, right?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't move divs that contain iframes.  This is to prevent people from moving an iframe under a mouse cursor to force them to click something (e.g. bank login )

Comment: You can move them, but the iframes reload. Which would actually work out quite nicely for displaying ads.